# (PHP) - Changing two substrings inside a string

Tags: php, string, substring

This is my BIG string

> BEGIN:VEVENT
>   UID:xxxxxx
>   DTSTAMP:xxxxxx
>   STATUS:CONFIRMED
>   CLASS:PUBLIC
>   URL:xxxxxx
>   SUMMARY:**YYYYYYY**
>   DESCRIPTION:xxxxxx; **YYYYYYY**; 
>   DTSTART:xxxxxx
>   DTEND:xxxxxx
>   GEO:xxxxxx
>   LOCATION:xxxxxx
>   END:VEVENT

I need to change position of the two "**YYYYYYY**" in SUMMARY/DESCRIPTION

I have to replace them without being specific since it is implemented in a much larger function. (This string is already sliced out of a 3700 line - Calendar)

Comment: What do you mean by **Change Position**, and what do you mean **Replace them without being specific**

Comment: I remember i used http://www.kigkonsult.se/iCalcreator/ for parsing/creating/editing/savingToDB iCal files ;)

Answer (score 0):

I would use regex replace with a replace method.

The rexex should have subselects for the 2 strings and you can then build the segment in the replace method and replace the lot of it.

```
/SUMMARY:(.+?).*?DESCRIPTION:.*?; (.+);
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace-callback.php

Answer (score 0):

it depends what you mean by "being specific". If you need to replace the values in specific keys (for example you know that you want to replace the values for the keys "SUMMARY" and "DESCRIPTION"), then it's just a matter of using a regular expression, or transforming the string into an array and replacing the values, something like this:

```
 //assuming $str is your string
$lines = explode("\n", $str);
foreach($lines as $k => $line)
{
   $parts = explode(":", $line);
   if ($parts[0] == 'SUMMARY') $lines[$k] = $parts[0].':'.'REPLACE_VALUE_FOR_SUMMARY';
   else if ($parts[0] == 'DESCRIPTION') $lines[$k] = $parts[0].':'.'REPLACE_VALUE_FOR_DESC';
}
$str = implode("\n", $lines);
```

the regex version should be something like this:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(SUMMARY:)(.+)/', '$1:NEWVALUE', $str);
$str = preg_replace('/(DESCRIPTION:)(.+)/', '$1:NEWVALUE', $str);
```

Comment: only problem is that I need to get the two values first... I don't just want to set new values to them. Instead I want to exchange their values. (value of summary <=> value of description)

Comment: this involves first reading the values and then setting them. in the second example written by me (with preg_replace): first do preg_match('/SUMMARY:(.+)/', $str, $matches); $summary_value = $matches[1]; then the same for description, and then use the values in the preg_replace calls

Answer (score 0):

find the postion of "SUMMARY:" and "DESCRIPTION:"
and replace with position.

OR

find the string between these position and replace that string